# express.js HTTP method vs REST api endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On express website:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

These are the HTTP methods that it supports:
get, post, put, head, delete, options, trace, copy, lock, mkcol, move, purge, propfind, proppatch, unlock, report, mkactivity, checkout, merge, m-search, notify, subscribe, unsubscribe, patch, search, and connect.

I have used REST API and notice that get, post , put are REST names too. But haven't came accross notify, unlock... What's the relationship between REST and HTTP methods?

Comment: "What's the relationship between REST and HTTP methods?" — They are the same thing (at least when doing REST over HTTP).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as simple switch statement.
If http method is `this` route to `that`.

**There is no strict mapping on specific HTTP method to specific REST api endpoint.**

Answer (score 0):

REST is a set of standards that dictate how the API works so that across all developers expected behaviors and protocols, rather than each person doing it individually. For example, one of the core concepts of a RESTful API is that the client and the server have to be separated.